# How to instantiate C++ component in QML - WITH Parameterized Constructor

Tags: c++, qml, qt-quick

In hypothetical example, I have a C++ component -

```
class Board : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //Q_PROPERTYs go here
    explicit Board(int rows, int columns)
    {
        matrix = std::vector<int>(rows, std::vector<int>(columns, 0));
    }

    ~Board()
    {
        matrix.clear();
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void checkAndUpdateAdjecentCells(int row, int column);
    //setters and getters here.

signals:
    void matrixUpdated();

private:
    Board(QObject *parent) = default; //i intend to do this.
    Board(Board& b) = delete;
    int nRows_, nCols_;
    std::vector<std::vector> matrix;
};
```

registered in `main()` like -

```
qmlRegisterType<Board>("SameGameBackend", 1, 0, "BubbleBoard");
```

**Question**

How do I instantiate this in QML such that the parameterized constructor is invoked ?

Expected QML code -

```
BubbleBoard{
    id: bboard
    rows: 10
    columns: 10
}
```

---

We can extend this question to include initializer list.
Had `nRows_` and `nCols_` been `const int`, 
constructor would have been

```
explicit Board(int rows, int columns):nRows_(rows), nCols_(columns){}
```

Is it possible to instantiate such components from inside QML ?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no such feature. See the answer below.

Answer (score 6):

May be a solution would be to register an uncreatable type and register a factory class which creates the object with parameters.

For instance I use a model factory to create sql models from C++ with filter parameters.

```
ModelFactory {
 id: modelFactory
}

ListView {
  model: modelFactory.createModel(filterparam1, filterparam2)
}
```

Comment: i tryed, but modelFactory.createModel returns `null`

Answer (score 5):

[Q_PROPERTY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) is the only way to send your parameters using QML property